# How to consume restful web service from Enterprise Application Client?

Tags: java, swing, web-services, rest, jms

I used the Auto generate feature of Swing Application to consume rest web service on a normal Swing application but now I try to copy the same code for the restful client and try to use it on an Enterprise Application Client of Netbeans and I get some error message.

This is the error message I am receiving.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder
    at currencyExchange.currencyExchangerClient.<init>(currencyExchangerClient.java:34)
    at com.sushan.displays.ExchangeWindow.jButton1ActionPerformed(ExchangeWindow.java:125)
    at com.sushan.displays.ExchangeWindow.access$100(ExchangeWindow.java:18)
    at com.sushan.displays.ExchangeWindow$2.actionPerformed(ExchangeWindow.java:62)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.ACCClassLoader.findClass(ACCClassLoader.java:237)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 40 more
```

Is there a different way of consuming rest client in an enterprise application client?

This is the code I use for consuming the restful web service:

```
private WebTarget webTarget;
private Client client;
private static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/RealEstateWebsite-war/webresources";

public currencyExchangerClient() {
    client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    webTarget = client.target(BASE_URI).path("RESTCurrencyExchangingService");
}

public String getXml(String currencyType, String amount) throws ClientErrorException {
    WebTarget resource = webTarget;
    resource = resource.path(java.text.MessageFormat.format("{0}/{1}", new Object[]{currencyType, amount}));
    return resource.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(String.class);
}

public void putXml(Object requestEntity) throws ClientErrorException {
    webTarget.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).put(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.entity(requestEntity, javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
}

public void close() {
    client.close();
}
```

The reason why I am trying to use the enterprise application client is because I couldn't find a way to implement message listener in my normal swing application. I need this desktop application to be able to use restful web service as well as listen for messages and consume them for display from the topic that is registered in my message driven bean. 
I know how to use JMS only with Enterprise Application Clients which is making this confusing for me and I don't get any pre-compilation error which I should If I was missing a library or something. I only get this error when initializing the rest client.

Answer (score 0):

According to this error, the swing application is still missing a library that is being used in the enterprise application. Maybe the code is compiling because the missing library is only necessary at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Put the required jar files in your class path. Also put all necessary jar files for REST in deployment assembly and clean build your project and then deploy.